# С помощью JSOUP спарсить текст!

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как мне достать весь текст из этого куска статьи? Обычным способом это не получается

```
<img class="alignleft" src="/images/news/89029.jpg"/>В новогодние праздники за лидерство в североамериканском бокс-офисе разгорелась нешуточная борьба: «<a href="/film/3513409/">Последние джедаи</a>» едва не уступили пальму первенства <a href="/film/2975183/">ремейку «Джуманджи»</a>. Более того, победу восьмому эпизоду удалось вырвать лишь к концу уикенда (29 декабря — 1 января), хотя некоторые аналитики сомневались в столь удачном окончании выходных для фильма <a href="/person/972948/">Райана Джонсона</a>.<br />
    <br />
    В итоге «<a href="/film/3513409/">Последние джедаи</a>» добавили в свою копилку еще $66,8 млн, собрав таким образом в североамериканском прокате $531,5 млн и опередив по этому показателю «<a href="/film/20952207/">Красавицу и чудовище</a>». Однако в мировом прокате, где новые «<a href="/film/3513409/">Звездные войны</a>» освоили $1,05 млрд, музыкальную сказку от студии Disney им только предстоит обойти.<br />
    <br />
    Примечательно, что из всего топа-5 только восьмой эпизод лишился части аудитории, хотя падение зрительского интереса к картине <a href="/person/972948/">Джонсона</a> составило скромные 6,6%. Пока лента на 28% отстает от «<a href="/film/3188527/">Пробуждения силы</a>», зато может похвастаться тем, что уже сейчас обошла <a href="/film/20953495/">первый спин-офф</a> франшизы. Показательным для «<a href="/film/3513409/">Последних джедаев</a>» станет следующий уикенд, когда фильм откроется в кинотеатрах Китая.<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://lostfilm.info/photo/3513409/1012543/"><div class="center"><img src="/images/news/89033.jpg"/></div></a><br />
    <br />
    Продолжает радовать своих создателей приключенческая комедия «<a href="/film/2975183/">Джуманджи: Зов джунглей</a>», которая несмотря на весьма скептические прогнозы сумела за 13 дней пребывания в прокате заработать $185,2 млн, практически удвоив сумму сборов оригинального фильма 1995 года (без учета инфляции). И хотя критики довольно прохладно отнеслись к ленте <a href="/person/329896/">Джейка Кэздана</a>, удачные юмористические вставки и очаровательный актерский состав сделали ее любимчиком зрителей в сегменте картин для семейного просмотра. Именно поэтому за праздничный уикенд аудитория «<a href="/film/2975183/">Зова джунглей</a>» выросла на 83%, позволив ему записать в свой финансовый актив дополнительные $66,3 млн.<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://lostfilm.info/photo/2975183/1007406/"><div class="center"><img src="/images/news/89032.jpg"/></div></a><br />
    <br />
    «<a href="/film/21020959/">Идеальный голос 3</a>» продолжает приносить студии Universal стабильный доход: на этих выходных триквел освоил еще $21,7 млн. Режиссер <a href="/person/2840232/">Триш Си</a> попыталась сыграть на ностальгических чувствах зрителей, однако небольшой прирост аудитории в праздники показывает, что киноманы уже устали от «Барденских Белл» и их выступлений. Хотя музыкальные номера в третьей части получились отменными — сказывается предыдущий опыт <a href="/person/2840232/">Си</a>, ранее работавшей над музыкальными клипами и «<a href="/film/3426548/">Шагом вперед</a>». Во всем остальном «<a href="/film/21020959/">Идеальный голос 3</a>» получился заурядным фильмом, который порой даже претендует на лавры шпионского боевика.<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://lostfilm.info/photo/21020959/1013468/"><div class="center"><img src="/images/news/89031.jpg"/></div></a><br />
    <br />
    Кому новогодние празднества принесли удачу, так это «<a href="/film/1461831/">Величайшему шоумену</a>». В свою первую прокатную неделю мюзикл от студии 20th Century Fox не продемонстрировал ничего выдающегося. Более того, критики разочаровались в ленте <a href="/person/1360896/">Майкла Грэйси</a>, хотя стоит отдать должное австралийцу: он прыгнул выше своей головы. Пусть «<a href="/film/1461831/">Величайший шоумен</a>» и получился весьма предсказуемым, но манера съемки превращает происходящее на экране в захватывающее представление, а его главная звезда, <a href="/person/69747/">Хью Джекман</a>, и танцует, и поет, и играет великолепно. Вероятно, поэтому в минувший уикенд зрители толпами отправились на киносеансы картины, увеличив ее аудиторию больше, чем на 100%, и пополнив кассу фильма на $20,9 млн. Правда, этого рывка недостаточно для итогового успеха, и пока с общей суммой в $54,4 млн и $84-миллионным бюджетом «<a href="/film/1461831/">Величайший шоумен</a>» претендует на звание одного из провалов года.<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://lostfilm.info/photo/1461831/1008871/"><div class="center"><img src="/images/news/89030.jpg"/></div></a><br />
    <br />
    Замыкает пятерку лучших мультик «<a href="/film/21052099/">Фердинанд</a>», также оказавшийся в числе тех, кому повезло в Новый год. За прошедшие выходные анимационная лента собрала в два раза больше, нежели неделей ранее, и благодаря дополнительным $14,9 млн у нее в копилке теперь имеется $57 млн.  
        <div class="hor-spacer"></div>
```

Вот так я пробую, не получается, достает все кроме статьи. Что посоветуете?

```
                    aboutNews = newsurl.select("div.wrapper div.container_12.main-container.relative div.grid_9 div[id] div.news-container img.alignleft");
                    imageNews = newsurl.select("div.wrapper div.container_12.main-container.relative div.grid_9 div[id] div.news-container img.alignleft");
                        Iterator titles = titleNews.iterator();
                        Iterator imagesNews = imageNews.iterator();
                        Iterator about = aboutNews.iterator();
                        while (imagesNews.hasNext()) {
                            Element title = (Element) titles.next();
                            Element imagenew = (Element) imagesNews.next();
                            Element aboutnew = (Element) about.next();
                            String a = imagenew.attr("src");
                            String b = aboutnew.text();
                            String c = title.text();
                            String f = "http://lostfilm.info" + a;
                            news.add(new CardNewsArrayList(c, f, b));
                        }
```